# How to make the tabs of viewPager to act as spinner?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a view pager in my app .I need the tab instead of being only text and image to be a spinner. I didn't find any tutorial about that and I need to know how can I implement that

Comment: Do you mean that you want to move between the tabs using a spinner?

Comment: No for every tab I need its header to be a spinner to change its content based on the spinner

Answer (score 1):

You must create a tablayout and set custom layout(contain spinner view) for each tab item like this:

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.aquablue); tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.layout.orangeprocess); tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(R.layout.shipping); tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(R.layout.deliver); tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setCustomView(R.layout.completedtxt); tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setCustomView(R.layout.cancelled);